# Export Historical user data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup a firebase project to track users events and for supporting push notification in my IOS and Android apps. In my apps I was registering for notifications when user completes sign up. However I have a number of users who just opened the app and didn't complete registration. I am planning to send notifications to such users to give them a nudge.

However I don't have the notification tokens for such users in my database. So is there any option to export the details of such users from firebase where I can grab their notification tokens?

I tried using big query and audiences but that wont work with historical data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using FCM tokens to send messages. In that case you will always needs an FCM token to send a message to a specific app/device.

FCM doesn't know anything about users of your app; all it knows about are the tokens.

So if you want to send a message to an app instance where the user didn't sign in, you'll need to store the token from the app in your database as soon as the app starts - even before the user signs in. Then when the user signs in, you can associate the token with their UID.

With those steps out of the way, you can query for database for tokens without an associated UID and send them a reminder to complete the registration.

Comment: I can see that in Firebase, using audiences we can filter users who installed app and not registered based on in app events and push notifications to them. So I am assuming that firebase has the user tokens stored somewhere. I am trying to see if I can export those tokens somehow?

Comment: In Google Analytics you can associate a user with events, which you can then use to build audiences. That information is not available in a public API or data export as far as I know though.